# Can you search JSON using Swifty-JSON?

Tags: swift, swifty-json

I am using SwiftyJSON with a large piece of JSON.  Using SwiftyJSON, is it possible to search the data using a unique identifier to retrieve the other objects?

For example.

```
{  
  "places": [  
    {  
      "name": "Place 1",  
      "id": 123,  
    },  
    {  
      "name": "Place 2",  
      "id": 456,  
    }  
]  
}
```

I want to use the `id = 123` to get the associated name.  This is all once the JSON has been loaded.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is from swifty JSON doc on Github :

```
//If json is .Dictionary
for (key: String, subJson: JSON) in json {
   //Do something you want
}
```

The first element is always a String, even if the JSON is an Array

```
//If json is .Array
//The `index` is 0..<json.count's string value
for (index: String, subJson: JSON) in json {
    //Do something you want
}
```

You can then just check if your id equals 123. Then you just do a loop in a loop, and if the places["id"]=123, then you have your object places.

I mean in algo :

```
for(places in JSON)
{
  if(places["id"] == 123) 
  {
  //my object is object
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you expand?  I can't seem to get that working (with many trial and errors with editing your suggestions).

Comment: Yes, you can look at my github, I just pushed your code :
[link](https://github.com/benobab/TestJSON)